# How can I add an external file in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am creating one application to get all the element details from an HTML file using the Angular CLI. I have used PHP to get file content but i am getting error:

```
./bodycontent/load.php file not found... zone.js:2933.
```

How can we resolve this issue?

```
  +-- src //folder
  |  |  
  +  | +-- app //folder
      | +-- >bodycontent//folder
             +-- bodycontent.component.spec.ts
             +-- bodycontent.component.ts
             +-- load.php
```

script:

```ts
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { Router } from '@angular/router';
  import * as jQuery from 'jquery';  
  import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-bodycontent',
  templateUrl: './bodycontent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bodycontent.component.css']
  }) 
  export class BodycontentComponent implements OnInit { 
    public href: string = "";
    url: string = "asdf";

    constructor(private router : Router) {}

    ngOnInit() {


        this.href = this.router.url;
        console.log(this.router.url);

         let url = "https://www.testing.com/test.html"; 

         let arr= null;
         $.post(this.router.url+"/load.php", { url: url,async: false},
            function(html) {

                $('#page').html(html); alert(html)
                let links = $('a');
                let title = $('a').attr('title');  

                let arr=[];
                for(let i=0; i < links.length; i++)
                {
                    arr.push(links[i]); 
                }
                 alert(arr);  
        }  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the file in the .angular-cli.json assets or in assets folder.

```
"assets": [
   "favicon.ico"
  ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response:). i am getting this error:zone.js:2933 GET http://localhost:8080/bodycontent/load.php 404 (Not Found). I have used this: this.router.url+"/load.php" for file path.  that is correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

For the PHP file to work, it needs to be in PHP interpreter. Angular CLI does not have that, it is just a static file server.

Possible solution would be to build your angular project using the angular CLI and move the build output and your PHP file to a server that supports PHP. You can start off with WAMP I guess.